# I am sending an error from the Backend but the Frontend does not register it

Tags: java, angular

I'm trying to send an error in my backend:

```
       if (true) {
           httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "error");
       }
```

but the fronted does not chatch it.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

        }
        return event;
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          localStorage.clear();
          sessionStorage.clear();
          this.nav.goToLogin('');

        return throwError(error); 
      })); 
  }
```

in the web console: 
event = http response {headers: httpheaders, status: 200, statustext: "ok" ...

What could be happening?

Comment: Check the backend code. If FE gets HTTP 200 and you're responding from the server-side with INTERNAL_SEVER_ERROR, FE should get HTTP 500 as response. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500.
On another note, unless you're building a very specific case for handling error 500 here, here's a good read on why you shouldn't throw 500 on any software error: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337147/is-it-acceptable-to-escalate-a-software-error-to-http-500